# How to speed up COLUMNS deleting function in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working through data in Google sheets, attempting to delete EMPTY COLUMNS based I have 600 so it take too much time

Any suggestions on how to speed this up?

Here is my code :

```
function delCols() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
var c = 600
var data = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, c).getValues()

Logger.log(data[0].length)
var delCol=0
for (var i = data[0].length; i >0  ; i--) {

if(s.getRange(1, c  ).getValue() =="") { s.deleteColumn(c);delCol=delCol+1 }
c=c-1
}
s.insertColumns(600-delCol, delCol);
  Logger.log(delCol)
}
```

Thank you in advance if you may help

Answer (score 1):

Create a new sheet, for example "Sheet0", for intermediate data. It can be hidden.
Run this script function to remove empty columns from the active sheet:

```
function removeEmptyColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      sheet0 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  // AHG is 600-th column (if I am not mistaken)
  var formula = "=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('" + activeSheet.getName() + 
    "'!A:AHG); \"select * where Col1 is not null\"; 0))";
  sheet0.getRange('A1').setFormula(formula);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var values = sheet0.getDataRange().getValues();
  sheet0.getRange('A1').clear();
  activeSheet.clearContents();
  activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

I believe it is faster, than column by column deletion. Some remarks:

1. There is a restriction for use of formulas on the active sheet, because we copy only values.
2. If you do not remove the formula in the script, then calculations will take place on every active cheet change, resulting in delays.
3. Please note, empty column detection is based on top cell value, as in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much Александр Ермолин but your solution is little bit complicated for my level. I don't understand Transpose and Query and whent i past the formula in cell, I got error.I was thinking about doing this with arrays if it is possible ?

Comment: [TRANSPOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) and [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) are well documented, fast and easier to use than scripting (to my mind). In addition, you may consider [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to be useful for the case. You have large data ranges and should use efficient tools to work with them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.